# load & unload movie in flash script

Tags: flash

i am loading two movie in flash one is audio file and second is video file when i unload any of file then load it, it works on starting but i want it on current time

Comment: Can you believe clarify what you're trying to do here? This is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

by the sounds of it you're using as2 and loadMovie() and the sound and video live inside a swf each. This is what I'm assuming since your question is pretty vague, as Jon pointed out.

When you load then, they might load at different times and video and sound won't synch.
If you're using as2 and loadMovie(), stop that and use MovieClipLoader and the [onLoadInit handler](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/MovieClipLoader.html#event:onLoadInit). Make sure your swfs containing audio and video do not autoplay. Have a boolean that turns true when both swfs are loaded and that's when you start playing them.

This is strange. Why not have the sound with the video in the first place ? and just load an FLV with the FLVPlayback component ? Or at least have the embedded FLV(which I hope isn't very long because Flash has issues with long FLVs in the timeline ) and audio in the same swf and load that.